# I want to make a list from the items that are checked in mat checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, list, checkbox

I have an `items` array `[Bille,Joe,Sam,Finn]` and a `friends` array `[]`.
I display individual `items` in a `mat-checkbox` each inside the following `HTML` template.

```
<span class="listLeft " *ngFor="let item of xyz">
   <mat-checkbox [labelPosition]= "'before'" class="custom-checkbox required" aria-label="checkbox" disableRipple="false">{{item}}</mat-checkbox>
</span>
```

Now, if i select lets say Bille And Joe from the `HTML` page, I want to populate the values to the `friends` array.

```
friends = [Billie,Joe]
```

Comment: My html if not visible is     <span class="listLeft " *ngFor="let item of xyz">
                                                    <mat-checkbox [labelPosition]=  "'before'" class="custom-checkbox  required" aria-label="checkbox" disableRipple="false">{{item}}</mat-checkbox>
                                            
                        
                                            </span>

Comment: Hey use "selection model" from cdk. Check out https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview there is quite alot of documentation and a stackblitz example:). Search for "checkbox" when you use the link.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vhukc - you can use mat-select multiple

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

.html

```
<span class="listLeft " *ngFor="let item of xyz">
     <mat-checkbox (change)='onChange(item)' [labelPosition]=  "'before'" class="custom-checkbox  required" aria-label="checkbox" disableRipple="false">{{item}}</mat-checkbox>  
</span>
```

.ts

```
  names = ["Bille", "Joe", "Sam", "Finn"];
  friends = []

  onChange(value: any) {
   if(this.friends.includes(value)) {
     this.friends.splice(this.friends.indexOf(value),1)
   } else {
     this.friends.push(value)
   }
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-wedra8?embed=1&file=app/checkbox-overview-example.html)**